# Is there any way to configure Amazon EC2 instances to support multicast discovery needed for EhCache

Tags: amazon-ec2, ehcache, multicast

Is there any way to configure Amazon EC2 instances to support multicast needed for EhCache auto-discovery? (through iptables hacks etc)/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no multicast between EC2 instances. Amazon does not allow it.

There is a straight answer on the FAQ
http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/#R4

You can submit a request to AWS, I am sure that you (we) are not alone facing a requirement to easily auto-scale an EHCache on amazon.

Terracotta seems to have a solution, cloud tools.
http://ww1.terracotta.org/documentation/3.7/cloud-tools/get-started

Comment: Broken link to terracotta

Comment: seems that i have the same problem with digitalocean (using hazelcast instead of EHCache). But need to be confirmed.

Comment: The answer is outdated, this is [now possible](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/overlay-multicast-in-amazon-virtual-private-cloud/).

Answer (score 4):

Dependent upon kernel configuration you might be able to overlay multicast on VPN connections manually wired up between each EC2 instance:

*original version:*

https://web.archive.org/web/20111129081152/http://www.slideshare.net/Franklin72/vpncubed-ipsec-to-ec2-gateway-test

*New version for 2014:*

http://www.slideshare.net/CohesiveFT/cohesiveft-vns3-configuration-documentation-for-amazon-aws

Comment: Broken link to slideshare.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a presentation about how to use JGroups-based clustering (e.g. EHCache, and JBoss AS) on AWS:

http://www.redhat.com/summit/2011/presentations/jbossworld/whats_new/wednesday/ban_w_310_running_in_the_cloud.pdf

You can configure JGroups to use TCP/IP and do discovery in many different ways.